# Password value does not pass-through Azure AD B2C to Azure Function via REST API during Sign-In

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Anyone pls advise?
I would like to get Input Password value from Azure Function to Azure AD B2C during Sign In.
I tried according to some sample; I received email value, but password value not returned to Azure Function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag5Kr.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can only operate on the password claim within the technical profile in which it is captured. You’d have to use a validation technical profile to call your rest api from the self asserted technical profile from which the password is captured from.